# Unable to determine the serialization information for *expression* using .Date

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to read from a mongoDB collection with a Date filter (only the Date, time should be ignored):

```
var filterDefinition = Builders<SomeClass>.Filter.Eq(p => p.SomeDateTimeProperty.Date, DateTime.Now.Date);
using (var cursor = await _someCollection.FindAsync(filterDefinition))
{ ... }
```

`SomeClass` and the `SomeDateTimeProperty` property look like this:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
[Serializable]
public class ReportConfiguration
{
    ...
    public DateTime SomeDateTimeProperty { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The code throws an `InvalidOperationException` when trying to `.FindAsync()`:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   MongoDB.Driver.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Unable to determine the serialization information for p
>   => p.SomeDateTimeProperty.Date

Everything works if I remove the .Date part in the filter (p.SomeDateTimeProperty.Date, DateTime.Now.Date), but I need a yyyy\mm\dd comparison regardless of the hh\mm.

Stacktrace says:

```
at MongoDB.Driver.ExpressionFieldDefinition`2.Render(IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
at MongoDB.Driver.SimpleFilterDefinition`2.Render(IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.CreateFindOperation[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options)
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindAsync[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollectionExtensions.FindAsync[TDocument](IMongoCollection`1 collection, FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at [...]
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried it without the .Date part?

Comment: Yes, removing the .Date part prevents the Exception, I added this clarification to the question - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using a between clause using Lt and Gt operators

```
 var b = Builders<SomeClass>.Filter;
 var date = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
 var filter = b.And(
        b.Gte(x => x.SomeDateTimeProperty, date), 
        b.Lt(x => x.SomeDateTimeProperty, date.AddDays(1))
        );
 ...
```

Comment: Yes, that's the current solution I approached and it works just fine, it's a good and clear workaround. However I am curious why the first approach doesn't work...

Comment: I think because .Date is a c# function on DateTime, that the MongoDb driver is unable to interpret when you try to apply it to a property on your Mongodb model property. You will find a lot of this when using the MongoDb c# driver, particularly when using Linq

Answer (score 1):

The Driver doesn't know how to serialize the Eq expression between two Dates.

Try doing ToString() to both Date parts:

```
var filterDefinition = Builders<SomeClass>.Filter.Eq(p => p.SomeDateTimeProperty.Date.ToString(), DateTime.Now.Date.ToString());
```

If that doesn't work, try something like this:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();    
var docs = _someCollection.asQueryable().Where(p => p.SomeDateTimeProperty.Date.ToString() == date);
```

Comment: Tried the first one, I get the same InvalidOperationException. For the second one I still get: 

'An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MongoDB.Driver.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: {document}{SomeDateTimeProperty}.Date.ToString() is not supported'