# Unable to compare date in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I'm very new to MongoDB, but have what I believed to be a very simple query.

I have a Protein object that inherits from IProtein (yes, my naming sucks)

```
public interface IProtein
{
    int Count { get; set; }
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I want to return the `FirstOrDefault` from the collection based on a date comparison of the `Date` field of the protein object and `Today`

```
    public IProtein GetProteinForDay(DateTime day)
    {
        var collection = _db.GetCollection<IProtein>(DB_COLLECTION);

        var query = collection.AsQueryable<IProtein>()
                              .Where(p => p.Date == day.Date);

        var protein = query.FirstOrDefault();
        return protein;
    }
```

Unfortunately, I've gone through so many different variations of trying to match dates using MongoDB (some using Linq, some not) that I've completely lost focus on how far I got with each one.

This is my current code, it returns the error `Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: p.Date`

What is wrong with my query (yes, it probably is something very simple) and how do I actually compare dates with a MongoDB / Linq query?

Comment: I think you may find your answer somewhere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023067/unable-to-determine-the-serialization-information-for-expression-using-date)

Comment: @AndrewWinterbotham I did work through that and several other answers on here, none of them seemed to work though. The above it what I settled on to ask the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, It's disappointing that .net DateTime doesn't work seamlessly with MongoDB driver. I believe support should be baked into driver.

Anyway you'll need to take couple of steps to make .net and MongoDB work together.

1) Decorate `Date` field in your interface with `BsonDateTimeOptions` attribute to tell MongoDB driver how to serialize .net DateTime. See [BsonDateTimeOptions Documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/1.5/html/5d0b1090-4781-64e8-ae35-4db9a3c12e04.htm)

Interface should looks like

```
public interface IProtein
{
    int Count { get; set; }

    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

2) In your `GetProteinForDay` function, replace

```
var collection = _db.GetCollection<IProtein>(DB_COLLECTION);
var query = collection.AsQueryable<IProtein>()
                              .Where(p => p.Date == day.Date);
```

with

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<Protein>(DB_COLLECTION);
var query = collection.Find(p => p.Date == day);
```

Notice that, I have replaced interface `IProtein` with concrete implementation of interface, in my case `Protein`.

**Update:** Full program is attached as reference.

Source document:

```
{
  _id: ObjectID('5964ebf315c46ab80b2c20f3),
  Count: 10,
  Date: '2017-07-11 00:00:00.000'
}
```

Test Program:

```
using System;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace mongoT
{
    public interface IProtein
    {
        ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        int Count { get; set; }

        [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
        DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }

    public class Protein : IProtein
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{nameof(Id)}: {Id}, {nameof(Count)}: {Count}, {nameof(Date)}: {Date}";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static string DB = "ProteinsDB";
        private static string COLLECTION = "Proteins";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = GetProteinForDay(DateTime.Now.Date);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        public static IProtein GetProteinForDay(DateTime day)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient();
            var db = client.GetDatabase(DB);

            var collection = db.GetCollection<Protein>(COLLECTION);
            var query = collection.Find(p => p.Date == day.Date);

            var protein = query.FirstOrDefault();
            return protein;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like I should know this, but I'm now getting "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IMongoQuery' because it is not a delegate type" on "(p => p.Date == day)"

Comment: @DarkHippo, I couldn't reproduce error your reported. Please check if you have latest driver. I have updated my answer with sample solution.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll give it a shot when I'm back at my laptop

Comment: Yep, your sample code works fine. I guess I need to do some refactoring